# Sphinx: select similar to mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, sphinx

How can I use select similar to mysql? 
for example i'd like to match words in `category=3`

What I've tried

```
    SELECT * FROM online WHERE MATCH('hello') and category=3 LIMIT 0,5; SHOW META;
    ERROR 1064 (42000): index online: no such filter attribute 'category'

describe online;
+------------+-----------+
| Field      | Type      |
+------------+-----------+
| id         | bigint    |
| title      | field     |
| full_story | field     |
| category   | field     |
| date       | timestamp |
+------------+-----------+
```

without and category=3

```
SELECT * FROM online WHERE MATCH('test') LIMIT 0,5;
+-------+------+
| id    | date |
+-------+------+
|  8190 | 2012 |
|  2865 | 2012 |
|  3843 | 2012 |
|  5362 | 2013 |
| 11201 | 2012 |
+-------+------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need category to be a attribute not a field.

There is an integer attribute type :)